# Typescript conditional argument types not working

Tags: typescript

Setting up some types..

```
type TContent = {
  _id: string;
  category_filters: IFilter[] | [];
  contentID: string;
  contentType: string;
  dateCreated: string;
  description_html: string;
  icon_url: string;
  importedContent: boolean;
  isBootstrapped: boolean;
  langLocale: string;
  lastUpdated: string;
  level: string | [];
  org: null;
  products?: IFilter[] | [];
  retired: boolean;
  roles: IFilter[] | [];
  subcontentOrder: [];
  success_html: string;
  tags: IFilter[] | [];
  title: string;
  trail_ids: string[];
};

type TSubcontent = {
  _id: string;
  assessment?: TAssessment;
  challengeTime: string;
  content: string;
  contentType: string;
  isBootstrapped: boolean;
  langLocale: string;
  org: string | null;
  retired: boolean;
  subcontentID: string | null;
  subContentType: string;
  tags: IFilter[] | [];
  title: string;
};
```

Use the types..

```
   function onUpdateTagPoints(points: number): void {
      const dispatchArg = filterActions.updateTagPoints({
        points: points,
        contentID: content.contentID || content.subcontentID,
        contentType: content.contentType || content.subContentType,
      });

      dispatch(dispatchArg);
    }
}
```

Fails with a ...

```
Property 'contentID' does not exist on type 'TContent | TSubcontent'.
  Property 'contentID' does not exist on type 'TSubcontent'
```

How is it possible to use conditional argument types?

Comment: there isn't enough information in your question to be able to answer, the error shown can't possibly be generated from the definition it must be in some line in the function. Please show some minimal code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok I've updated it

Comment: Try to publish minimum reproducable code example in TS playground.
It is hard to figure out  what type expect updateTagPoints method

Comment: Please consider editing the code here to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), so that others can demonstrate your issue for yourself without unrelated issues.  Right now if I drop that code in I get [errors I need to wade through](https://tsplay.dev/KwXx1w) before getting close to answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a typeguard in order to define right type in use. You could try something like that:

```
export const isContentType(x: TContent | TSubcontent) : x is TContent {
 return x && x.contentId
}
```

Then use:

```
contentID: isContentType(content) ? content.contentID : content.subcontentID,
```

Comment: if you can't access `contentID` in a `TContent | TSubcontent` then you will get an error in the type guard.

Comment: Sorry, you can  consider to cast type of x to unknow